# ValueError: matmul when trying to fit sklearn's linear regressor to pandas dataframe instanses

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I've been trying to perform a simple multivariate linear regression on some dummy data using sklearn. I initially passed sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit numpy arrays and kept getting this error:

ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 2 is different from 1)

which I thought was due to some mistake with the transposition of my arrays or something, so I pulled up a [tutorial that used pandas dataframes](https://towardsdatascience.com/simple-and-multiple-linear-regression-in-python-c928425168f9) and set out my code in the same way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

VWC = np.array((0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1))
Sensor_Voltage = np.array((515,330,275,250,245,240))

X = np.column_stack((VWC,VWC*VWC))
df = pd.DataFrame(X,columns=["VWC","VWC2"])
target = pd.DataFrame(Sensor_Voltage,columns=["Volt"])

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(df,target["Volt"])
x = np.linspace(0,1,30)
y = model.predict(x[:,np.newaxis])
plt.plot(VWC, Sensor_Voltage)
plt.plot(x,y,dashes=(3,1))
plt.title("Simple Linear Regression")
plt.xlabel("Volumetric Water Content")
plt.ylabel("Sensor response (4.9mV)")
plt.show()
```

And I still get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vivian Imbriotis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\simple_linear_regression.py", line 16, in <module>
    y = model.predict(x[:,np.newaxis])
  File "C:\Users\Vivian Imbriotis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_base.py", line 225, in predict
    return self._decision_function(X)
  File "C:\Users\Vivian Imbriotis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_base.py", line 209, in _decision_function
    dense_output=True) + self.intercept_
  File "C:\Users\Vivian Imbriotis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\extmath.py", line 151, in safe_sparse_dot
    ret = a @ b
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 2 is different from 1)
```

I have been banging my head against this for hours now and I just don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Scikit-learn, numpy, and pandas are all the latest versions; this is on python 3.7.3

SOLVED: I am very silly and misunderstood how np.newaxis worked. The goal here was to fit a quadratic to the data, so I just needed to change:

```
x = np.linspace(0,1,30)
y = model.predict(x[:,np.newaxis])
```

to

```
x = np.columnstack([np.linspace(0,1,30),np.linspace(0,1,30)**2])
y = model.predict(x)
```

I am sure there is a more elegant way to write that but eh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You train your model using shape of (6,2) dataset.if you check shape of df

`df.shape = (6,2)`.

And when you try to predict you are trying with different shape of dataset.

`x.shape=(30,1)`

what you need is to use the correct shape of dataset.Try this

```
x = np.linspace((0,0),(1,1),30)
y = model.predict(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this error when using sklearn and LinearRegression, turns out the issue was that I was passing the Y variable to the LinearRegression object in the first position, and the X variables in the second position. But you actually pass the X variables first, and then Y variables - the opposite of the order you use in R with R's lm().

Hopefully this helps someone out someday.